# Add Previous Node value and Number

Tags: xml, xslt, addition

I am trying to add `1` to the previous occurrence of the node. The logic behind it is, if there node before does not match on three fields specified; then set position to `1`. If the previous node DOES match the previous node then take the value from the previous position and add `1`.

I have create the XSLT to complete this, however i do not know how to add `1` to the previous node.

When i use the snippet of code:

```
<xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::orderLine/position + '1'"/>
```

The response i get in the output is:

```
<position>NaN</position>
```

The XSLT i am using is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template
        match="/order/orderLines/orderLine[sku = preceding-sibling::orderLine/sku and lineId = preceding-sibling::orderLine/lineId]"/>

    <xsl:template match="/order/orderLines">
        <xsl:for-each select="/order/orderLines/orderLine">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>


                <xsl:choose>

                    <xsl:when
                        test="lineId = preceding-sibling::orderLine/lineId and sku = preceding-sibling::orderLine/sku and lineTrackingUrl = preceding-sibling::orderLine/lineTrackingUrl">
                        <position>
                            <!-- THE ISSUE IS HERE -->
                            <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::orderLine/position + '1'"/>
                            <!-- THE ISSUE IS HERE -->
                        </position>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <position>1</position>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>

            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Example Input:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<order>
    <orderLines>
        <orderLine>
            <lineId>4</lineId>
            <sku>1111111</sku>
            <lineTrackingUrl>![CDATA[1111111111]]</lineTrackingUrl>
        </orderLine>
        <orderLine>
            <lineId>4</lineId>
            <sku>1111111</sku>
            <lineTrackingUrl>![CDATA[1111111111]]</lineTrackingUrl>
        </orderLine>
        <orderLine>
            <lineId>4</lineId>
            <sku>1111111</sku>
            <lineTrackingUrl>![CDATA[1111111111]]</lineTrackingUrl>
        </orderLine>
        <orderLine>
            <lineId>4</lineId>
            <sku>1111111</sku>
            <lineTrackingUrl>![CDATA[1111111111]]</lineTrackingUrl>
        </orderLine>
        <orderLine>
            <lineId>3</lineId>
            <sku>1111111</sku>
            <lineTrackingUrl>![CDATA[1111111111]]</lineTrackingUrl>
        </orderLine>
        <orderLine>
            <lineId>3</lineId>
            <sku>1111111</sku>
            <lineTrackingUrl>![CDATA[1111111111]]</lineTrackingUrl>
        </orderLine>
        <orderLine>
            <lineId>3</lineId>
            <sku>1111111</sku>
            <lineTrackingUrl>![CDATA[1111111111]]</lineTrackingUrl>
        </orderLine>
        <orderLine>
            <lineId>3</lineId>
            <sku>1111111</sku>
            <lineTrackingUrl>![CDATA[1111111111]]</lineTrackingUrl>
        </orderLine>
    </orderLines>
</order>
```

If you use the example input above it illustrates perfectly why this doesnt work:

**Expected outcome:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<order>
    <orderLine>
        <lineId>4</lineId>
        <sku>1111111</sku>
        <lineTrackingUrl>![CDATA[1111111111]]</lineTrackingUrl>
        <position>0</position>
    </orderLine>
    <orderLine>
        <lineId>4</lineId>
        <sku>1111111</sku>
        <lineTrackingUrl>![CDATA[1111111111]]</lineTrackingUrl>
        <position>1</position>
    </orderLine>
    <orderLine>
        <lineId>4</lineId>
        <sku>1111111</sku>
        <lineTrackingUrl>![CDATA[1111111111]]</lineTrackingUrl>
        <position>2</position>
    </orderLine>
    <orderLine>
        <lineId>4</lineId>
        <sku>1111111</sku>
        <lineTrackingUrl>![CDATA[1111111111]]</lineTrackingUrl>
        <position>3</position>
    </orderLine>
    <orderLine>
        <lineId>3</lineId>
        <sku>1111111</sku>
        <lineTrackingUrl>![CDATA[1111111111]]</lineTrackingUrl>
        <position>0</position>
    </orderLine>
    <orderLine>
        <lineId>3</lineId>
        <sku>1111111</sku>
        <lineTrackingUrl>![CDATA[1111111111]]</lineTrackingUrl>
        <position>1</position>
    </orderLine>
    <orderLine>
        <lineId>3</lineId>
        <sku>1111111</sku>
        <lineTrackingUrl>![CDATA[1111111111]]</lineTrackingUrl>
        <position>2</position>
    </orderLine>
    <orderLine>
        <lineId>3</lineId>
        <sku>1111111</sku>
        <lineTrackingUrl>![CDATA[1111111111]]</lineTrackingUrl>
        <position>3</position>
    </orderLine>
</order>
```

**Actual Outcome:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<order>
    <orderLine>
        <lineId>4</lineId>
        <sku>1111111</sku>
        <lineTrackingUrl>![CDATA[1111111111]]</lineTrackingUrl>
        <position>0</position>
    </orderLine>
    <orderLine>
        <lineId>4</lineId>
        <sku>1111111</sku>
        <lineTrackingUrl>![CDATA[1111111111]]</lineTrackingUrl>
        <position>1</position>
    </orderLine>
    <orderLine>
        <lineId>4</lineId>
        <sku>1111111</sku>
        <lineTrackingUrl>![CDATA[1111111111]]</lineTrackingUrl>
        <position>2</position>
    </orderLine>
    <orderLine>
        <lineId>4</lineId>
        <sku>1111111</sku>
        <lineTrackingUrl>![CDATA[1111111111]]</lineTrackingUrl>
        <position>3</position>
    </orderLine>
    <orderLine>
        <lineId>3</lineId>
        <sku>1111111</sku>
        <lineTrackingUrl>![CDATA[1111111111]]</lineTrackingUrl>
        <position>0</position>
    </orderLine>
    <orderLine>
        <lineId>3</lineId>
        <sku>1111111</sku>
        <lineTrackingUrl>![CDATA[1111111111]]</lineTrackingUrl>
        <position>5</position>
    </orderLine>
    <orderLine>
        <lineId>3</lineId>
        <sku>1111111</sku>
        <lineTrackingUrl>![CDATA[1111111111]]</lineTrackingUrl>
        <position>6</position>
    </orderLine>
    <orderLine>
        <lineId>3</lineId>
        <sku>1111111</sku>
        <lineTrackingUrl>![CDATA[1111111111]]</lineTrackingUrl>
        <position>7</position>
    </orderLine>
</order>
```

The reason this is not working is because of the match it does to could the previous nodes:

This is the code:

```
<xsl:when
    test="lineId = preceding-sibling::orderLine/lineId and sku = preceding-sibling::orderLine/sku and lineTrackingUrl = preceding-sibling::orderLine/lineTrackingUrl">
    <position>
        <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::orderLine/lineId)"/>
    </position>
</xsl:when>
```

You will see that the `test` for the when is `lineId = preceding-sibling::orderLine/lineId and sku = preceding-sibling::orderLine/sku and lineTrackingUrl = preceding-sibling::orderLine/lineTrackingUrl` however the one for the actual count is just `preceding-sibling::orderLine/lineId`

So its just matching ALL lineIds not just the ones that have the same lineId and same Sku and same TrackingUrl as the one before, and the one before that...etc. How do i restrict this?

**Revised Version**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template
        match="/order/orderLines/orderLine[sku = preceding-sibling::orderLine/sku and lineId = preceding-sibling::orderLine/lineId]"/>

    <xsl:template match="/order/orderLines">
        <orderLines>
        <xsl:for-each select="/order/orderLines/orderLine">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>               

                <xsl:choose>

                    <xsl:when
                        test="lineId = preceding-sibling::orderLine[4]/lineId and sku = preceding-sibling::orderLine[4]/sku">
                        <position>
                            <xsl:value-of select="'5'"/>
                        </position>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when
                        test="lineId = preceding-sibling::orderLine[3]/lineId and sku = preceding-sibling::orderLine[3]/sku">
                        <position>
                            <xsl:value-of select="'4'"/>
                        </position>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when
                        test="lineId = preceding-sibling::orderLine[2]/lineId and sku = preceding-sibling::orderLine[2]/sku">
                        <position>
                            <xsl:value-of select="'3'"/>
                        </position>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when
                        test="lineId = preceding-sibling::orderLine[1]/lineId and sku = preceding-sibling::orderLine[1]/sku">
                        <position>
                            <xsl:value-of select="'2'"/>
                        </position>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <position><xsl:value-of select="'1'"/></position>

                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>

            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </orderLines>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Is there a neater way of doing the multiple when statements, this only works for 4 items, is there a way of doing it for unlimited items. At the moment this is fine but further down the line if it needs expanding how would i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by using the count() function, so the line in question looks like this:

`<xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::orderLine/lineId)"/>`

This automatically populates the correct number into `<position/>`

This therefore means the whole XSLT looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="start" select="'0'"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template
        match="/order/orderLines/orderLine[sku = preceding-sibling::orderLine/sku and lineId = preceding-sibling::orderLine/lineId]"/>

    <xsl:template match="/order/orderLines">
        <xsl:for-each select="/order/orderLines/orderLine">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>


                <xsl:choose>

                    <xsl:when
                        test="lineId = preceding-sibling::orderLine/lineId and sku = preceding-sibling::orderLine/sku and lineTrackingUrl = preceding-sibling::orderLine/lineTrackingUrl">
                        <position>
                            <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::orderLine/lineId)"/>
                        </position>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <position>1</position>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>

            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `<xsl:number>` for this. Sometimes comes handy, if you want to avoid doing calculations manually, and commiting some trivial error.

Comment: This does not work. I have done some testing on it, and it is failing. I will explain above why it is failing.

Comment: That would be interesting -- you probably didn't specify correctly the various attributes of `xsl:number`

Comment: Example added at the bottom of the main post.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see any `xsl:number`.